# How can i use my css in html

Tags: html, css, django

The items are inside my django project

I have the templates directory like this :

```
|base.html
|
|rules
   | 
   |style_base.css
```

and i set the link label in my base.html which could be:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/rules/style_base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but i can't get the css when i use firebug to check if it works.

What firebug shows to me is 'There are no rules. You can create a rule.'

and i see a optional selection says 127.0.0.1:8000/rules/stye_base.css

I don't want to cite it via urls but my local directory.

So how should i cite style_base.css?

Comment: You should put your css files in your static directory: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first forward-slash, it will look from the current location.

With the forward-slash it looks from the root-directory, which is not necessarily the same as the current location.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `settings.py` file and change these variables values:

```
STATIC_URL = '/rules/'
STATICFILES_DIR = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates/rules'), )
```

And use it in templates:

```
<link type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}style_base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```